# shared Preferences in flutter stop the app

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, preferences, shared

I'm calling shared prefs in page I made as splash screen

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getPreferences().then((value){
      Timer(
        Duration(seconds: 2),
        (() => {
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(new MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) => value))
        }),
      );
    });
  }
```

and here is my method

```
   getPreferences() async {
    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();//??**
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();//the same with home screen in the skip button
    bool loadingScreen=prefs.getBool('seen');
    print("loadingScreen = $loadingScreen");
    StatefulWidget _screen= LoginScr();
     if (loadingScreen == null|| loadingScreen == false){
       _screen = Tut();
     }
     else if (loadingScreen == true){
       userName = prefs.getString('userName');
       if(userName ==null||userName=="null") {
         print(userName+' userName in main');
         _screen = LoginScr();
       } else {
         print(userName +'userName in main');
         _screen = HomePage();
       }
     }
     return _screen;
  }
```

By the way I don't know what is this line
`Widge,tsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();`//??**
and here is my log

> Performing hot restart... Syncing files to device Android SDK built
> for x86... Restarted application in 1,776ms. I/flutter ( 8982):
> loadingScreen = true E/flutter ( 8982):
> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception:
> NoSuchMethodError: The method '+' was called on null. E/flutter (
> 8982): Receiver: null E/flutter ( 8982): Tried calling: +(" userName
> in main") E/flutter ( 8982): #0      Object.noSuchMethod
> (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5) E/flutter ( 8982): #1
> _SplashSCRState.getPreferences (package:plaster/UI/SplashSCR.dart:138:24) E/flutter ( 8982):
>  E/flutter ( 8982): #2
> _SplashSCRState.initState (package:plaster/UI/SplashSCR.dart:26:5) E/flutter ( 8982): #3      StatefulElement._firstBuild
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4765:58) E/flutter (
> 8982): #4      ComponentElement.mount
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:5) E/flutter ( 8982):
> #5      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14) E/flutter (
> 8982): #6      Element.updateChild
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18) E/flutter (
> 8982): #7      SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6118:14) E/flutter (
> 8982): #8      Element.inflateWidget
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14) E/flutter (
> 8982): #9      Element.updateChild
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18) E/flutter (
> 8982): #10     ComponentElement.performRebuild
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4652:16) E/flutter (
> 8982): #11     Element.rebuild
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4343:5) E/flutter ( 8982):
> #12     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4606:5) E/flutter ( 8982):
> #13     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:5) E/flutter ( 8982):
> #14     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14) E/flutter (
> 8982): #15     Element.updateChild
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18) E/flutter (
> 8982): #16     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6118:14) E/flutter (
> 8982): #17     Element.inflateWidget
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14) E/flutter (
> 8982): #18     Element.updateChild
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18) E/flutter (
> 8982): #19     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6118:14) E/flutter (
> 8982): #20     Element.inflateWidget
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14) E/flutter (
> 8982): #21     Element.updateChild
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18) E/flutter (
> 8982): #22     ComponentElement.performRebuild
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4652:16) E/flutter (
> 8982): #23     StatefulElement.performRebuild
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4800:11) E/flutter (
> 8982): #24     Element.rebuild
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4343:5) E/flutter ( 8982):
> #25     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4606:5) E/flutter ( 8982):
> #26     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4791:11) E/flutter (
> 8982): #27     ComponentElement.mount
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:5) E/flutter ( 8982):
> #28     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14) E/flutter (
> 8982): #29     Element.updateChild
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18) E/flutter (
> 8982): #30     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6118:14) E/flutter (
> 8982): #31     Element.inflateWidget
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14) E/flutter (
> 8982): #32     Element.updateChild
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18) E/flutter (
> 8982): #33     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6118:14) E/flutter (
> 8982): #34     Element.inflateWidget
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14) E/flutter (
> 8982): #35     Element.updateChild
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18) E/flutter (
> 8982): #36     ComponentElement.performRebuild
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4652:16) E/flutter (
> 8982): #37     StatefulElement.performRebuild
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4800:11) E/flutter (
> 8982): #38     Element.rebuild
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4343:5) E/flutter ( 8982):
> #39     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4606:5) E/flutter ( 8982):
> #40     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4791:11) E/flutter (
> 8982): #41     ComponentElement.mount
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:5) E/flutter ( 8982):
> #42     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14) E/flutter (
> 8982): #43     Element.updateChild
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18) E/flutter (
> 8982): #44     ComponentElement.performRebuild
> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4652:16) E/flutter (
> 8982): #45     Element.r

Comment: Can you please share the whole content of your main method

Comment: 'prefs.getString('userName')' returns null. in if you are checking if userName is null then you are adding a string to it.

Comment: To add something to what @mahdishahbazi's answer, "ensureInitialized" creates and initializes the Flutter Binding. You can find more info on https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/TestWidgetsFlutterBinding/ensureInitialized.html

Comment: here is the main
void main() async {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

Comment: 'prefs.getString('userName')' returns null. sure it will be null on first app run

Comment: Your username is null, add a check to see if the username is not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You trying to print log:

```dart
print(userName + ' userName in main');
```

When `userName` is `null`:

```dart
if (userName == null || userName == "null")
```

And it raises exception. Modify `print` method usage ant try again. It should be like this:

```dart
userName = prefs.getString('userName');
if(userName == null || userName == "null") {
  print('first start, userName in main is null');
  _screen = LoginScr();
} else {
  print('$userName is userName in main');
  _screen = HomePage();
}
```

Comment: thank you, that's work.
what about this line     WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

Comment: You can delete it. Problem is in accessing to variable that contains `null`.

Comment: i can't delet it
You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center.